# Swift: How to use FairPlay streaming?

Tags: ios, fairplay

I just found out that there is a service in apple called FairPlay that has to do with playing encrypted video files.

**My question:**

If I have encrypted videos on the ios device:

How should I use FairPlay (should I pay for the service, I am a single developer not a team)?

I don't know how to use the service, please help me figure this out.

**update:**

I have videos that are paid, I made the videos. But I don't want users sharing these when they get downloaded on their devices. So I came around FairPlay and don't know from where to start with this. How to use it?

Comment: is your content protected with FairPlay DRM?

Comment: @PeterPajchl no but I don't know from where to start?

Comment: @PeterPajchl can you please help.

Comment: perhaps you should then elaborate on your question a bit more (update); what is it you are trying to accomplish. do you have your own content you are trying to protect with DRM solution or decrypt 3rd party content already encrypted?

Comment: @PeterPajchl updated the question.

Comment: In that case I would suggest to start here https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/. There are other DRM solutions but they all differ in client support, licensing fees and complexity of integration.

Comment: @PeterPajchl I saw the site, but I don't know how the process happens. They say I must be a team agent which I don't know what it means. And they say I must request deployment package?

Comment: Team Agent - as in highest user role of your Apple developer program which I assume you have. If DRM is new for you, you might benefit from "ready" solutions such as https://www.ezdrm.com/ (not associated) and similar services.

Comment: @PeterPajchl how is that similar to fairplay, and how that will help play offline videos that are encrypted on ios?

Comment: It all depends on your use-case; how does the user gain access to the video; is it always on the device; is it streamed live with offline support; do you require DRM solution at all or do you need to only encrypt the video data at rest with no licensing support required...

Comment: @PeterPajchl I only want to let user download videos then I will encrypt them. The only thing left is to play them. What to you advice to do? Note there is no online streaming.

Comment: depending on the level of protection you require you could encrypt the content e.g. with AES before downloading the file; once downloaded you can then decrypt on the fly while playing the video using eg. `AVPlayer` with `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`; you would need to find a secure way of providing the decryption key to the iOS client.

Comment: @PeterPajchl does AVPlayer play on the fly encrypted videos?

Comment: @PeterPajchl and encrypted videos are able to be seeked?

Comment: Yes, `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` is exactly the place (set of callbacks) where `AVPlayer` gives you ability to do any work on the requested bytes as needed. Hence you can decrypt and let the player consume ready bytes. Seeking makes not difference.

Comment: @data have you found the solution?